# modx Decrement a TV to obtain 0

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I need my `[[+idx]]` tv to start at 0 instead of 1 so I tried this:
`[[+idx:decr]]` or `[[+idx:substract=`1`]]` but it gives me -1 (minus one).
Does anyone know another way to obtain 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using this in chunk for getImageList works (at least for me):

```
[[+idx:decr]]
```

It gives: 0,1,2,3 ....

P.S. using modx revo 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

set your template variable default to 0 when you create the variable.

What are you trying to do, your question is vague at best.

**UPDATE**

ok - what I think will work for you is to write a snippet to do the math... where ever you call the [[+idx]] instead write a snippet

```
 [[!FixIDX? &itemindex=`[[+idx]]`]]
```

then in your FixIDX snippet just do the math with php and return the corrected index. Though perhaps a custom output modifier would be the better way to go: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+(Output+Modifiers)

Though looking at the docs, your code should certainly work - I see no reason for it not to.

Comment: ok, sorry i thought it was pretty clear.  I created a news system with text, title and link in each news. [[+idx]] is the id of each migx's news. Tv's are created like this with migx for example:{"field":"image","caption":"image","inputTVtype":"image"},
{"field":"titre_actu1","caption":"Titre de l'actualité 1"}, 
{"field":"actu_date1","caption":"actu_date1","inputTVtype":"date"},So tv"s doesn't really exists physicaly. Now i need to display the  id of each news but it must start at 0, i have no other choice to get compatible with an other system. So i want to know if there is an other way.

Comment: hm so migx is creating the idx variable? hmm. I'll update my answer [maybe 'vague was a bit harsh, knowing you were using migx was pretty important.]

Comment: Is there a way to do something like that in a snippet :
 
if ([[+idx]]==1)
  echo "0";